# Redirect to another/external website from ASP.NET Core Web API with swagger

Tags: cors, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using ASP.NET Core and trying to redirect a Web API that has been called via Swagger to another website (like google.com), but I get this error:

> Failed to fetch. Possible Reasons:
>
> CORS Network Failure URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS
> request.:

Here is the action method:

```
[HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    return Redirect("https://www.google.com/");
}
```

The console log is:

> Access to fetch at 'https://www.google.com/' (redirected from
> 'http://localhost:5278/WeatherForecast') from origin
> 'http://localhost:5278' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Is there any way to enable CORS in Swagger?

Comment: Hi @Saeid Mirzaei, `TypeError:Failed to fetch` indicates that you tried to fetch the URL in Swagger UI, via an AJAX/fetch request. Which you of course can not do. Users need to be send to this URL directly, so that they can verify via their browser's address bar, that they are indeed sending their credentials to Google, and not some phishing site.

Comment: @Rena Yes, exactly, but the question is how can I directly forward it to Google?